# Nonetheless or nevertheless?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

I have looked up the difference but I cannot decide which word to use. 
 I am talking about my high school experience.  "There was always something to be done, from [this] to [that]. Nonetheless/nevertheless, I learned a lot."

Basically like through the intensity, through the chaos, through doing all the aforementioend things, I learned a lot.

Please tell me which would be correct in the sentence and why. Thanks!

Comment: Neither choice is wrong. Check out the link that JLG provides above for a bunch of answers to a question very much like yours.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of these words is the same, I think. But "nevertheless" is used much more often. Maybe that's the reason "Nevertheless, I learned a lot" sounds more comfortable...